# Confusion about coordinate representation and their relations and curve fitting

Tags: geometry, curves, coordinates

Can someone review a problem I am having related to coordinates and curve fitting

**Part 1**

I have a curve in the coordinate frame XY. This curve is represented by a list of $(x,y)$ coordinates

I also have a list of "distances" calculated as the distance between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_0,y_0)$ and so on

For example, let's say I have the points:

$(0,0),  (1,1), (1,2), (3,1), (5,5)$ then the list of distance would be $[\sqrt 2, 1, \sqrt 3 ,\sqrt 6]$

**Part2**

If I take *only* the X component $([0,1,1,3,5])$ and I try to fit a cuadratic equation $y=a+bx+cx^2$ with y being the distances, am I representing the curve parametrically?

I mean I can understand curve fitting when y is y and x is x
but can someone understand what kind of coefficients I am finding if I curve fit only one component (x or y) versus the distance?

I am sorry for the confused question, I am confused.

EDIT: I made a huge mistake of interpretation.
Here

> I try to fit a cuadratic equation $y=a+bx+cx^2$ with y being the
> distances, am I representing the curve parametrically?

the correct way was

> I try to fit a cuadratic equation $y=a+bx+cx^2$ with y being the
> coordinates and x the distances, am I representing the curve
> parameticaly?

And the answer is yes. The distance acts as the parameter and the coordinates are $x=x(d),y=y(d)$

Comment: I do not understand the question.  If you create a model with `dist = quadratic(x_coord)` then you are describing the distance from the origin and not the curve. BTW you mention a cubic equation but show a quadratic equation.